# I'm hitting a race condition in my Laravel application when trying to conditionally INSERT or UPDATE, any suggestions...?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb, race-condition

My users need to be able to upload files to my site, so I've implemented a file uploader widget on the frontend. It allows for multiple uploads at once, and each upload triggers code one file at a time to save the file to the DB.

The problem is that files need to be stored as an array in a single row in the database (I know, I know... legacy reasons).

In English pseudocode, here's what's happening:

1. Laravel sees a new file has been uploaded
2. Laravel checks whether or not any files (at all) have been uploaded to this entity
3. No files have been uploaded yet? Create a new record to store that file.
4. There are already files for this entity? Update the existing record to add this file to the array.

The problem is that when multiple files are uploaded at once in quick succession for the first time, Laravel has entered the first file in the database moments *after* the second file has conducted it's check to see if any files already exist. So we end up with duplicate rows, rather than it updating them in to a single record.

If I upload 5 files at once, typically I'll get 4 rows in the database - 3 single entries and one double-entry, that managed to catch up in time.

Any practical ways to get around this problem? I know I should be using a many-to-one database schema here, but I've greatly simplified an already complex situation for brevity!

This is Laravel 5.2 using a MySQL InnoDB database.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  When you see one new file, wait a little while.  Then look for 'all' the files and deal with them.

Plan B:  Store a timestamp with the record.  When another file is noticed, see if there is an existing record with a 'recent' timestamp.  If so, assume it is part of the same 'group'.

Both Plans will *occasionally* have hiccups -- mostly because of the vague definition of "at once".

Perhaps you currently have another problem:  A file is half uploaded when you grab it, and you get an incomplete file?

The 'real' answer is to have some 'message' uploaded when they are finished.  Then, don't start the processing until you see it.  (I realize this is probably not practical.)